# reading and writing bit to a file C++

Tags: c++, bit, bitwise-operators, huffman-code

I'm writing a program using Huffman algorithm to compress text file. I have tested my program by just printing the printing ASCII character to file and it worked fine. However, now I have to implement using bits and my program doesn't work. It seems like I'm not reading or writing the right bits. 
Here is the result of my testing:
In the input file I put `abc` the input file to compress it. Then I uncompress it the out out is `aaa`. 
 Below is a snippet of how I read and write bits

```
class BitInput {
    istream& in;  // the istream to delegate to
    char buf;     // the buffer of bits
    int nbits;     // the bit buffer index

public:

BitInputStream(istream& s) : in(s), buf(0), bufi(8) { }
~BitInputStream //destructor
{
  delete in;
};

/** Read the next bit from the bit buffer.
 *  Return the bit read as the least significant bit of an int.
 */
int readBit(){
    int i;
    if(nbits == 8){
        buf = in.get();
        nbits = 0;
    }
    i = (1 & buf>>(7-nbits)); //This could be the problem, I'm not getting the writing bit
    nbits++;
    return i;
}

/** Read a char from the ostream (which is a byte)*/
int readChar(){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 7; i>=0; i--) 
        sum = (sum*2) + readBit();
    return sum;
}
```

---

```
class BitOutput {
    ostream& out;  // the istream to delegate to
    char buf;     // the buffer of bits
    int nbits;     // the bit buffer index

public:

    BitOutput(istream& s) : in(s), buf(0), bufi(8) { }

    /* Write the least significant bit of the argument */
    void writeBit(int i){
        //Flush the buffer
        if(nbits == 8){
            out.put(buf);
            out.flush();
            nbits = 0;
            buf = 0;
        }
        buf = buf | (i<<(7-nbits)); //Did it write the right bit to ostream ?
        nbits++;
    }

    /** Write a char to the ostream (a byte) */
    void writeChar(int ch){
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) 
            writeBit((ch >> i) & 1);
    }
```

Comment: We need to see the destructor of BitOutput. There's a good chance there's a bug in there.

Comment: oops i forgot to put i in the paramter. I edited my code

Comment: If you use a 32bit buffer and you write out bytes, that means at most 7 bits can remain in the buffer so you can write up to 25bit code words to the buffer without special logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Write the least significant bit of the argument */
void writeBit(){
  int i; // <-- HERE
  //Flush the buffer
  if(nbits == 8){
   out.put(buf);
   out.flush();
   bufi = 0;
   buf = 0;
  }
 buf = buf | (i<<(7-nbits)); //Did it write the right bit to ostream ?
 nbits++;
}
```

You never assign `i` any sensible value. So when you shift it, you're shifting junk.

You probably wanted:

```
/* Write the least significant bit of the argument */
void writeBit(int i){
  //Flush the buffer
  if(nbits == 8){
   out.put(buf);
   out.flush();
   bufi = 0;
   buf = 0;
  }
 buf = buf | (i<<(7-nbits)); //Did it write the right bit to ostream ?
 nbits++;
}
```

Also, show us the destructor of BitOutput. There's a good chance there's a bug in there too.

Comment: actually I didn't write the destructor because I declared it in the stack

Comment: @JoeCool You need to write a destructor. Otherwise, you're not always writing the last few bits.

Comment: I added the destructor

Comment: @JoeCool Your destructor doesn't write the last few bytes. Worse, it `delete`s something that's not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
    //Flush the buffer

    if(nbits == 8){
        out.put(buf);
        out.flush();
        bufi = 0;
        buf = 0;
    }
```

Does not reset nbits to 0.